# mysql insert and select between 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

i am looking for a better way to handle the following problem.

```
custData
--------
ID | Code
1  |  A
2  |  B

prodData
--------
ID | ProdID
1  | prodA
2  | prodB
3  | prodC
```

and i would like to keep a record in this table:

```
custProdPrice
--------
ID | Cust | Prod
 1 |  A   | prodA
 2 |  A   | prodB
 3 |  A   | prodC
 4 |  B   | prodA
 5 |  B   | prodB
 6 |  B   | prodC
```

i was getting it done by using the following query

```
create view  CashPOSDB.viewertable as select Code, ProdID as pid, BelongTo
from CashPOSDB.custData cross join CashPOSDB.prodData

AND

insert into CashPOSDB.custProdPrice(Cust, Prod, BelongTo)(select Code, Pid, BelongTo from
(select Code, pid, belongTo from CashPOSDB.viewertable UNION ALL
select Cust, Prod, BelongTo from CashPOSDB.custProdPrice) t group by Code, Pid);
```

It does the job, but it seems like its missing some result sometimes or inserting duplicate rows.

Also, I would like it to check so that when I insert a new Prod `prodD`, it would check in `custProdPrice` and see if cust A and B already has a row of

```
A | prodD
b | prodD
```

and insert it if it doesn't exist.

So what would the best way be to optimize this?

Comment: What are `Code`, `ProdID`, and `BelongTo`? They're not columns in the tables you showed. And which tables in your queries are Table A and Table B?

Comment: Create a composite unique constraint on `(Cust, Prod)` and then use [IODKU](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: You can do the automatic insert using a trigger.

Comment: @Barmar yo ucan ignore BelongTo, and Code = cust, prodID = prod

Comment: Why don't you edit the question so that the table names and columns match your queries, instead of telling us to ignore things?

Comment: And the calls to `new MySqlCommand` seem to be irrelevant. Just post the SQL queries.

Comment: Use `UNION DISTINCT` instead of `UNION ALL` to prevent returning duplicates from the query.

Comment: @barmar sorry about that, i have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Give the `custProdPrice` table a unique index on `(Cust, Prod)` to prevent duplicates:

```
ALTER TABLE custProdPrice ADD UNIQUE INDEX (Cust, Prod);
```

Then use `INSERT IGNORE` to skip duplicates.

There doesn't seem to be any reason to `UNION` with `custProdPrice` when inserting into `custProdPrice`. Just insert the cross product.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO CashPOSDB.custProdPrice (Cust, Prod, BelongTo)
SELECT Cust, Prod, BelongTo
FROM CashPOSDB.viewertable
```

To automatically add new rows to `custProdPrice`, use a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER addCustProdPrice
AFTER INSERT ON prodTable
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT IGNORE INTO custProdPrice (Cust, Prod, BelongTo)
    SELECT c.Cust, NEW.Prod, NEW.BelongTo
    FROM custData;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, just one question if you don't mind answering. i am using c# right now linked to mysql, just wondering if the trigger should just run once, or i should call it once a while or how does it work. thank you